# How to JGit blame a file before commit?

Tags: java, jgit, blame

**Context:** My merge ran into conflicts and I have a file like this example:

*Foo.txt* (merged)

```
1
<<<<<< HEAD
2-master
======
2-side
>>>>>> df803849788fde47965b3dc8f07f07d48320ea9c
3
```

**Question:** In order to get the developers who actually changed the conflicting lines, how to blame result file (above) prior to the commit? It works for `git blame Foo.txt`

**Problem:** I tried to do the following, but the blame is `null` inside the loop.

```
MergeResult m = runMerge(aScenario);
BlameCommand blamer = new BlameCommand(git.getRepository());
BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(mergedfilepath)));
BlameResult blame = blamer.setFilePath(mergedfilepath).call();
for (int i = 0; (line= br.readLine())!=null ; i++) {
    // the blame at this point is null.
    PersonIdent person = blame.getSourceAuthor(i);
    System.out.println(person.getName() + ": "+ line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the *source* of the traversal should be the result contents.

Starting from there you can loop over the changed regions and ask for the author. For example:

```java
BlameResult blameResult = git.blame().setFilePath( ... ).call();
int size = blameResult.getResultContents().size();
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
  System.out.println( blameResult.getSourceAuthor( i ) );
}
```

At least for lines added to the work directory version of the file, an author named *Not Committed Yet* is returned.

However, your code should be prepared cope with `getSourceAuthor()` returning `null`. The JavaDoc states that the return value *may be null*.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the actual difference to my actual solution apart from the fact that I created a variable to hold the the line content. If  `...` means the file path this is what my `mergedfilepath` holds. I checked the path of the file and it is correct. I used your piece of code and got the same `null` value.

Comment: At which line is `null` returned?

Comment: I meant, for which line of the file to merge did `getSourceAuthor()` return `null`?

Comment: I can't say that once the variable `blameResult` is `null`, right?

Comment: I am afraid, I don't understand the above comment. Could you please tell, based on the snippet in your question, for which value of `i` does `getSourceAuthor( i )` return `null`?